# PostgreSQL 11 installer for Windows x86?

Tags: c++, postgresql, visual-c++, libpq

I need to build an x86 Windows application using libpq.lib. Before I only used x64.
I'm currently using an installation from postgresql-11.6-1-windows-x64.exe. In the name it says 'x64' allthough on https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads, in the column title it says 'Windows x86-64'. So I assume there might be x86 binaries as well, but where? This is confusing.

Comment: x86-64 is a synonym for x64. For a 32-bit application you would need x86-32. You probably do not perform another full installation just to get a 32-bit libpq though. There is a [conan recipe](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/libpq/all/conanfile.py) for building it from source, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are no ready-made 32-bit Windows binaries provided for PostgreSQL v11.

You'll have to [build it from source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-windows.html), which won't be difficult.

Comment: Thanks. So, as I guess from chapter 17.1.2, I have to run "build" from an x86 Native Tools Command Prompt, after having installed all the required 3rd party software

Comment: Yes. I have done it myself, and i am not a Windows person.